# abaqus muti-job submit one by one without gui blocking？

Tags: python, abaqus

waitForCompletion() command work good but it's gui blocking. i try use callback monitorManager.addMessageCallback() and it seems that callback can't  handle time-consuming command ,throw the error 'xml parsing error'.

Comment: i tend to just write a stand alone shell or python script for such things

Comment: Thank you for your reply.that's exciting and enlighten me.i think the command waitForCompletion() hybrid with gui update and time-consuming operation .so write a individual script may help. it's a little difficult for me now.